# How to remove blank spaces in Spark table column (Pyspark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, sparktable

I would like to remove blank spaces from all values in a specific column(purch_location). I am using a spark table rather then a dataframe or SQL table (but I can use dataframe or SQL table if need be).

Here is how my spark table was generated:

```
dataset = spark.table("trans")
cols = dataset.columns
dataset.show(5)
+----------+-------------+-------+--------------------+--------------+---+---+
|purch_date|  purch_class|tot_amt|       serv-provider|purch_location| id|  y|
+----------+-------------+-------+--------------------+--------------+---+---+
|06/11/2017|     Printing|  -0.66|   CARDS AND POCKETS|              |  0|  0|
|03/11/2017|Uncategorized| -17.53|             HOVER  |              |  1|  0|
|02/11/2017|    Groceries| -70.05|1774 MAC'S CONVEN...|     BRAMPTON |  2|  1|
|31/10/2017|Gasoline/Fuel|  -20.0|              ESSO  |              |  3|  0|
|31/10/2017|       Travel|   -9.0|TORONTO PARKING A...|      TORONTO |  4|  0|
+----------+-------------+-------+--------------------+--------------+---+---+
```

I have attempted the following function **pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
dataset1=dataset.select(regexp_replace(col("purch_location"),"\\s+",""))
```

Which removes the blank spaces AFTER the value in the column but not before. It also gets rid of the rest of my columns which I would like to keep.

```
+-------------------------------------+
|regexp_replace(purch_location, \s+, )|
+-------------------------------------+
|                                     |
|                                     |
|                             BRAMPTON|
|                                     |
|                              TORONTO|
|                                     |
|                             BRAMPTON|
|                             BRAMPTON|
|                                     |
|                                 null|
|                          MISSISSAUGA|
|                                     |
|                             BRAMPTON|
```

Any idea how I can resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a dataframe, this should work:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import trim
dataset = dataset.withColumn("purch_location", trim(df. purch_location))
```

- [PySpark Reference](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.trim)
- [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155821/trim-string-column-in-pyspark-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`pyspark.sql.functions.trim`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=trim#pyspark.sql.functions.trim):

> Trim the spaces from both ends for the specified string column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import trim

dataset.select(trim("purch_location"))
```

To convert to null:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import length trim, when

df.select(when(length(trim("purch_location")) != 0, trim("purch_location")))
```

> I am using a spark table rather then a dataframe

`SparkSession.table` returns `DataFrame`:

```
spark.range(1).createOrReplaceTempView("df")
type(spark.table("df"))
# pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
```